# How to create a form in Django that fill the fields on a related model

Tags: python, django, forms

I Have a Model that have a OnetoOne relationship with django.contrib.auth.models auth.

When I create one User Model I send a signal to the Profile Model which is related to this User. Then the Profile Object is created, but I can't figure out how to fill the others fields of Profile Object. Eg.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Could some one help me? How can I fill these bio, location and birth_date on a form?

Edit:
I found a Solution. don't know if its the best practices. Inside forms.py override the save()

```
def save(self, commit=True):
   # Save the provided password in hashed format
   user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
   user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
   user.save()
   user.profile.location= self.cleaned_data["location"]
   user.profile.save()
   return user
```

Comment: Why do you have two receiver functions listening to the same `post_save` signal? I think the second receiver (`save_user_profile`) gets called but the first (`create_user_profile`) doesn't. Can you remove the second receiver and test if the code works?

Comment: The second receiver seems utterly pointless.